# jQuery Validate are hiding inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I'm trying to validate a short form with jQuery Validate

this is my function:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#addForm').validate({
        rules: {
            "nombre": {
                required: true
            },
            "cajas": {
                required: true
            },
        },

        messages: {
            "nombre": "Campo obligatorio",
            "cajas": "Campo Obligatorio",
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my form:

```
<?= form_open('Sucursales/agregarSucursal', 'class="form-inline targen text-center" id="addForm"') ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Número de Cajas: </label>
            <input type="text" name="cajas" id="cajas" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-inverse btnInline" id="add">Agregar</button>
        </div>
<?=form_close()?>
```

When i try to make the validation leaving the fields empty, the input is hidding i don't know why and i can't figure my error.

Can you help me guys?

Thanks in advance

These are the images of the form and the hidden inputs when you hit the button when the fields are empty

[image: normal from]

[image: hidden inputs]

JsFiddle: [My JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sznqcrom/)

Comment: What do you mean by hiding? Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all guys, i already found the cause of this:

I don't know why but removing

```
<div class="form-group"></div>
```

That contains the input and label of the form makes that all works like a charm

[image: Now is working :)]

Answer (score 0):

If your script is correct.Then replace view file as follows:

```
<? echo form_open('Sucursales/agregarSucursal', array('class'=>'form-inline targen text-center', 'id'=>'addForm')); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Número de Cajas: </label>
            <input type="text" name="cajas" id="cajas" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse btnInline" id="add">Agregar</button>
        </div>
<? echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: did u load `form helper` in controller.

Comment: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');`

Comment: rather than using autoload. load it on controller's constuctor `$this->load->helper('form');` hope it works fine.